# Declaring a Reference inside Function Parameter List

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to do something funky with macros and to do it, I need to do something even funkier. To give an example of what I'm trying to do, consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

int set_to_three(int& n) {
    n = 3;
    return 0;
}

int main() {

    int s = set_to_three(int& t); // <-- Obviously this wouldn't compile

    t += 5;

    std::cout << t << std::endl; // <-- This should print 8
    std::cout << s << std::endl; // <-- This should print 0

    return 0;
}
```

So as you can see, I want to call a function, declare its parameter, and capture the return value of the function in exactly **ONE** expression. I tried using the comma operator in various funky ways, but no results.

I was wondering if this is at all possible, and if so, how could I do it? I'm thinking it may be possible using comma operators, but I simply don't know how. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, in case you need to know which compiler I'm using.

Comment: Why bother?  The language wasn't designed to easily support this (you can tell, because loop-scoped variables, which are similar, *are* designed to be easily supported).  This isn't going to help code readability.  The best things this could help with are obfuscation and cramming your code to fit on one page...

Comment: This isn't for a practical, real world project. It's simply one of those "I'm doing this just to say I can." scenarios. I wanna see if I really can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have two `int`s, this will work:

```
int t, s = set_to_three(t);
```

Note that this is not comma operator.

Were the types of `s` and `t` different, it wouldn't be possible IMHO.

Comment: The issue is they're not both `int`s. One of them is an `int&`, and it has to be a reference. That's the tricky part!

Comment: A reference bound to what? In your code, you have only variable `s`. BTW with reference to int and int, it would work.

Comment: A reference bound to whatever variable `set_to_three()` decides.

Comment: `set_to_three()` cannot decide what is its parameter (passed by reference) bound to, because it is bound before the function starts (to an lvalue chosen by the caller). Also, your `set_to_three` function only changes the value of its parameter, it doesn't try to rebind the reference...

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. Thanks for taking the time to explain.